# Pointer to 2D array as function parameter

Tags: c++, arrays, pointers, multidimensional-array

This C++ code worked for me so far:

**Main.cpp:**

```
unsigned __int16** image_data; 
image_data = Grabber->get_image_data(1);
```

**interface.cpp:**

```
unsigned __int16** Grabber::get_image_data(int image_num) {
    unsigned __int16 **pixel_values = 0;
    pixel_values = new unsigned __int16*[height];
    for (int h = 0; h < height; h++) {
        pixel_values[h] = new unsigned __int16[width];
        for  (int w = 0; w < width; w++) {
            pixel_values[h][w] = ...;
        }
    }
    return pixel_values;
}
```

But now I would like to pass the array as pointer to the function.
I tried it like in following code, but it doesnt work anymore.

**Main.cpp:**

```
unsigned __int16** image_data;
Grabber->get_image_data(1, &image_data);
```

**Interface.cpp:**

```
int Grabber::get_image_data(int image_num, unsigned __int16*** image_data) {
    *image_data = new unsigned __int16*[height];
    for (int h = 0; h < height; h++) {
        *image_data[h] = new unsigned __int16[width];
        for  (int w = 0; w < width; w++) {
            *image_data[h][w] = ...;
        }
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Are there any errors in reasoning by me?

Comment: #define dosen't work for me, you are getting compiler error?

Comment: Sorry, no compiler error

Comment: I've edited out the dots; if they contain important code, you should include them. If not, it doesn't matter and you can just leave them out.

Comment: You shouldn't store the image data like that; it's by far easier and better to utilize a flat buffer (that is, `__int16*`), and manually calculate the index. Better still, use `std::vector<int16_t>`, which utilizes the standard typedef and automatically manages its memory.

Comment: A better solution would be to pass by reference

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`*image_data[h]` means `*(image_data[h])` (that is, `image_data[h][0]`), not `(*image_data)[h]` (or `image_data[0][h]`).
The latter is what you want.

It's easier to get it right if you introduce a local variable:

```
int ..::get_image_data(int image_num, unsigned __int16*** image_data) {
    ...
    unsigned __int16** data = new unsigned __int16*[height];
    *image_data = data;
    for (int h = 0; h < height; h++) {
        data[h] = new unsigned __int16[width];
        for  (int w = 0; w < width; w++) {
            data[h][w] = ...;
        }
    }
    return 0;
}
```